# VS Code error - No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code for C and C++ but whenever I try to compile and run the code I always get this error statement:

```
bash: ./trya.cpp: No such file or directory.
```

I have tried various command lines before but nothing seems to work.

[image: screenshot]

What's going on here? How can I fix this?

Comment: There's 2 major issues: First your terminal is not opened in the same directory as your code, second you are trying to run C++ source code directly, which doesn't work - you need to compile it first

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the file `trya.cpp` is inside `Documents` directory. I think in the terminal, you are not inside `Documents`. Secondly, you cannot run the .cpp file as `./trya.cpp`. You have to compile the .cpp file first(using some cpp compiler like **g++**) which will give you an object file (like `a.out`) that you can run as `./a.out`.

Answer (score -2):

This problem only occurred when there was space in the name of file. It got resolved as soon as i removed the space in the name of the file or replaced it with underscore.